# Hashcat first wordlist then brute force if nothing found

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

I'm trying to run my hashcat as automated and efficient as possible.

I have a file with NTLM hashes:

```
607C4CDCDA0EFBF023C4DEA52DF90641
D25ECD13FDDBB542D2E16DA4F9E0333D
AAD063F78DA1183CBD8BD7812FADF9C6
CAD4D65FCEA4B029A54DC1161A0C0456
38D7BBBC05F6BBB4ABC047E707029429
BFED4B770BF3578B26B623ED98F9091A
53760E5D6473ECDE30E04C0C3926D857
```

(this is just a test to optimize the process, so more or less random passwords)

I want to crack those with hashcat.

To start, I'd like to use a dictionary attack, something like rockyou, or another big wordlist with real passwords, I'll see what's going to be best to use.
So for that, I'd go with something like

`hashcat -a 0 -m 1000 hashesFile /opt/useful/SecLists/Passwords/Leaked-Databases/rockyou.txt`

For the hashes that can't be cracked with the provided wordlists, I'd like to run a bruteforce attack for passwords between 8 and 12 characters, containing special characters, numbers lower + upper case letters. I don't really understand the mask attack though.

Also, is there a way to combine those two so the remaining hashes automatically are tried to crack with a mask attack?

To explain what I'm trying to do: dumping NTLM hashes from active directory and then cracking them as fast and efficient as possible, whereas it's okay to only crack about 90% of the hashes.

If you have a better idea of what modes to use, please feel free to help me with that.

Comment: To combine the two you could just do `hashcat {insert arguments for dictionary attack} ; hashcat {insert arguments for brute force}`

Comment: @nobody wouldn't this then also try to crack the hashes with bruteforce, that have already been cracked with the dictionary attack?

Comment: I haven't used hashcat for some time, but I seem to remember that hashcat stores already cracked hashes in a potfile (if that's the correct name) so it doesn't have to crack those hashes again. (Edit: [Yes, my memory was correct](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#what_is_a_potfile) )

Comment: @nobody right, I remember that as well :) Can you help me with the brute-force/mask attack as well?

Comment: Can't be bothered to test this but it should go something like `hashcat -a 3 -m 1000 -i --increment-min=8 hashesFile ?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a
`

Comment: @nameless Hashcat is able to remember already cracked passwords, so it wont attempt to crack them again. Also since the hashes arent uniquely salted, there would be almost 0 performance loss anyway